# C++ Initialize inherited template base classes

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to pass arbitary parameters during construction to classes inherited through template parameter packs. Consider this example:

```
struct Zero {
    Zero() {}
};

struct Two {
    Two(int, int) {}
};

template <class... Pack>
struct User : Pack... {
    template <class... Params>
    User(Params... p) : Pack(p)... {} // How to do this correctly?
};

auto test = User<Zero, Two>(1,2);
```

If I now try to construct an object of type `User<Zero, Two>` **how can I pass the `Params` to the correct constructor?**

The most obvious workaround would be to have a tuple constructor taking exactly one tuple for each type `User` could accept, but this requires me to modify `Zero` and `Two`, which is very difficult in my use case.

Is this possible? Ohter possible workarounds are welcome as well.

Comment: not necessarily you'd have to modify `Zero` or `Two`, you'd just need  a `template<typename> T make_foo(tuple)` that unpacks the tuple and calls the constructor.

Comment: @user463035818 could you elaborate that with an example? I don't see how correct unpacking would be possible in context of the constructor.

Comment: @user463035818 Brian already did so. It is indeed possible. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: great, because i didnt manage to find out how to do it yet, and have to go to sleep urgently :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the `User` constructor accept a sequence of tuples, and then forward the arguments from each individual tuple to the corresponding base class.

```
template <class... Tuples>
User(Tuples&&... t) : Pack(std::make_from_tuple<Pack>(std::forward<Tuples>(t)))... {}
```

Note that due to guaranteed copy elision, temporaries of type `Pack...` will not be instantiated.

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d14e2e17772774cd)

Comment: Using the default copy constructor to construct each subclass is a very neat solution. Thanks for pointing that and the make_from_tuple function out to me.